# How to render youtube video in YII2 DetailView widget

Tags: video, youtube, yii2, detailview

I'm displaying you-tube video on front end of the website. Admin can provide the you-tube source from embedded code from Site back end. I want to have a preview on view page. Following is the code I tried but it is displaying the iframe tags as it is (I know this is not the right way)

```
[
    'attribute'=>'source',
    'value' => !empty($model->source) ? '<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="'.$model->source.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' : NULL,
],
```

is there any thing like it has for image format:

```
[
    'label'=>'Image',
    'attribute'=>'userInfo.image',
    'format' => ['image',['width'=>'100','height'=>'100']],
],
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Format `html` or `raw` will help you.

```
[
    'format' => 'raw',
    'attribute'=>'source',
    'value' => !empty($model->source) ? '<iframe class="embed-responsive-item" src="'.$model->source.'" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>' : null,
],
```

Comment: This helped me. Thank you :)