# yii2:use video in use yii\bootstrap\Html

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, yii, yii2, yii2-extension

i want use video in DetailView

```
  'attribute' => ['media_id',
                'format' => 'html',
                'value' => function ($model)
                    {


                    $image = app\models\Media::find()->where(['id' => $model->media_id])->asArray()->one();



                $url = $image['url'];

                $host = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'];

                return Html::video("$host/" . $url, ['width' => '60px']);
                },
            'label' => 'عکس',
        ],
```

how to use video in HTML for this section?

this is my error  for use video :

```
name":"Exception","message":"Call to undefined method yii\\bootstrap\\Html::video()"
```

Comment: there is not an Video() function is HtmlHelper http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html  .. you should wraute flat html code

Comment: This might help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32859125/how-to-render-youtube-video-in-yii2-detailview-widget

Answer (score 0):

There is not a HtmlHeper   Html::video() function so you should use flat video tag  eg:

Assuming you are using a DetailView widget  you should use

```
echo DetailView::widget([
  'model' => $model,

  'attributes' => [
              [
                'format' => 'raw',  // or html
                'value' => function  ($model)  {

                    $image = app\models\Media::find()->where(['id' => $model->media_id])->asArray()->one();
                    $url = $image['url'];
                    $host = Yii::$app->params['uploadPath'];
                    return '<video width="60" height="240" controls>
                              <source src="' .$host. DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR  . $url'" type="video/mp4">
                            </video>' ;
              },
            'label' => 'عکس',
        ]
      ],
]);
```

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-helpers-html.html

http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-helper-html.html

Comment: answer  updated ..  (missing $url)   but check for  real $path .. real complete url and your real  video type  .. mine is suggestion

Comment: return '<video width="60" <height="240" controls>   <source src="' . $host . DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR . $url . '" type="video/mp4">         </video>';
                
again td is blank ! video tag is not in td tag! ;-(

 link is correct with this :"$host/" . $url

Comment: I think @scaisEdge make an error in the code: look the first line, before height="240" there is "<", try to remove it like this: 
<video width="60" height="240" controls>

Comment: anyway i have updated  the answer with a code for DetailView widget    .. and remember that the anonymous function for detailView work starting from version 2.0.11